# php E_WARNING don't stop the process return false only?

Tags: php, warnings

I am facing a little problem with php, I want to write in a file but if is empty and the function `file_exists()` return true I can proceed with the writing function or to append data, but if the file don't exists I am force to make another option to create the file in this case i use `file_put_contents` and the function make the file by her self. Any way i want to use only silent function like this: `@filesize('file.txt')` without the `@` i get a warning like the file don't exists and pass on, I want to know if is reliable to use the function with the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)`(@)`. Thank you in advance!

And my code:

```
if (@filesize('entries.txt') > 0 ){
    file_put_contents('entries.txt', ',' . time(), FILE_APPEND);
}else {
    file_put_contents('entries.txt', time());
}
```

**The result i came with is as follow:**

```
if( !file_exists( $entries )) file_put_contents( $entries, '');
$smilliseconds = filesize( $entries ) >= 10? ','. $milliseconds: $milliseconds;
```

Comment: Although I haven't tried it, I'm pretty sure you can do without the whole `if` statement and just use your first `file_put_contents()` line. Have you tried that (putting the comma or a new-line after the input for example)?

Comment: Yes i made it without `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't use the `@` operator - ever. It masks problems that you otherwise need to know about and there is nearly always a better approach. For example, you could combine your `file_exists` check like this:

```
if (file_exists('entries.txt') && filesize('entries.txt') > 0 ){
```